# Any experience with cstore_fdw?

Tags: postgresql, columnstore

It looks like there is a (finally) an [open source columnar and compression extension](http://www.citusdata.com/blog/76-postgresql-columnar-store-for-analytics) for Postgres.

I wonder if anyone had any experience with it yet?

I've worked with Greenplum for years, but I've been looking desperately for the open source alternative.

Comment: Given how new it is, and how slow-moving the kinds of organisations that want column stores often are, you'll probably be in the forefront of people looking to apply it to real world uses.

Comment: @Edmon did you end up using Citus?

Comment: I did a long while ago but then transitioned to Parquet, so did no spend too much time with it.

Answer (score 3):

you get an impression of the performance looking at the comparison with a real column store: 
https://www.monetdb.org/content/citusdb-postgresql-column-store-vs-monetdb-tpc-h-shootout